# How do single-pixel cameras work?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, camera, medical-physics, photonics

To obtain images using a single-pixel camera we need a Digital Micromirror Device (DMD) because single-pixel cameras only possess a single detector ([article](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-16370-x)).

From my understanding, a single-pixel detector can only detect the intensity of a single spatial point, whilst an array of detectors would be able to recreate the whole image as it would have many detectors because it would detect the intensity of the several points of the picture.

This makes sense, but then I have come across the following image for the experimental setup showing the pattern created by the DMD and the image projected onto the detector.

[image]

My limited understanding of the subject **makes me think that the image projected onto the THz detector, which is labeled of Collection Optics in the picture, has many pixels instead of a single one**.

**Shouldn't the DMD only allow a single-pixel to go through?**

I know that my train of thought is probably wrong because it would take ages to create the image because a lot of measurement would be necessary. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does not equation (1) in your cited paper explain this?

Comment: I have understood the problem now, I had forgotten I had the question set here as no one had answered, the whole signal is "decoded" by a set of equations, each equation representing a "mask".
This didn't make sense to me as I thought that the signal would just be a mess, and impossible to decode. But it makes sense now.